# Angular2 Google pie-chart visualization

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization

I am trying to develop a web app with Angular2 and it contains a google pie chart.

I created a Directive for pie-chart, and here it's code.

```
@Directive({
selector: 'pie-chart'
})

export class PieChartDirective {
    el: HTMLElement;
    w: any;

private _content: any = {};

@Input()
set content(c: any) {
    this._content = c;

    this.draw();
}
get content() { return this._content; }

constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.w = window;

    this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;

    if (!this.w.google) { console.error("Google chart yuklenmedi.."); };
}

draw() {

    var data = this.w.google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Hedef ve Üstü', this._content.hedeF_UST],
        ['Hedef Altı', this._content.hedeF_ALT]
    ]);

    let options = {
        "backgroundColor": '#f1f8e9',
        width: '100px',
        title: this._content.name,
        colors: ['#088A4B', 'red'],
        chartArea: {
            left: "5%",
            top: "20%",
            height: "75%",
            width: "90%"
        }            
    };


    (new this.w.google.visualization.PieChart(this.el))
        .draw(data, options);
}
```

}

then I used it in app component. Until this point there is no problem, it works with IE 10,11 and Edge, and Chrome. But **Firefox** has problems. It visualize the chart view very small.

[This is chrome and IE view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e4F0.png)

and

[This is firefox view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppjSE.png)

Comment: is the chart drawn before it is shown?

Comment: I use this directive in a component sth like <pie-chart [content]='anArrayHere'> 
In this case, is it shown before drawn ? @WhiteHat

Comment: try setting specific width _and height_ in the chart options, as a number -- instead of `width: '100px'` -- `width: 100` --> see [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own directive I would suggest using existing GoogleChartComponent class from ng2-google-charts module. You can see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728736/372939